# Permission Denied ( publickey) while ssh to ec2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance 
Stopped it 
Again started it .

Got the following error

```
Aloks-MacBook-Pro:AWS alokmandloi$  ssh -i working_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
3d:f2:79:cc:38:66:83:71:1b:86:6c:7e:36:ad:27:bc.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/alokmandloi/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/alokmandloi/.ssh/known_hosts:11
RSA host key for ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I looked up over for a solution and found http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/how-to-fix-offending-key-in-sshknown_hosts-file/

Which suggested that i remove the 11th entry in known_hosts. After doing that i get the following error

```
Aloks-MacBook-Pro:AWS alokmandloi$  ssh -v -i working_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com [184.73.22.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file working_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file working_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 3d:f2:79:cc:38:66:83:71:1b:86:6c:7e:36:ad:27:bc
debug1: Host 'ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/alokmandloi/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: working_key.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have the wrong key or the wrong address for the instance (which has rejected your key).

Comment: Or the wrong username.

Comment: Possibly -- but `ubuntu` is a default username on many standard AMIs.

Comment: Only if they're Ubuntu ones.

Comment: Well.... yes. :-)

Comment: Stranger things have happened than someone firing up Amazon Linux while reading an Ubuntu-oriented tutorial. :-p

Comment: Stranger things keep me employed :-)

Comment: Since i restarted the instance the address changed and i did not notice that. Now i am able to connect with the new address

Answer (score 0):

If you stopped and started your instance, your public IP & hostname changes.  Even if you're using an ElasticIP, 'stopping' it will disassociate the EIP.

Check back in your AWS Console and see what the new Public IP/Hostname is, you might be trying to connect to the old DNS name, which is likely assigned to someone else's instance now.

Comment: If inside of a VPC (I'm not sure why anyone *wouldn't* use a VPC at this point), EIP->EC2 mappings persist through stop/start cycles.

Answer (score 0):

it is better because more fail-prove to remove the offending hostkey with

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

in your case

```
ssh-keygen -R ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

If you are sure your secret-key is correct, you may also verify on the server that `.ssh/authorized_keys` has the right permissions (`700` for `.ssh/`, `600` for `.ssh/authorized_keys`)

Answer (score 0):

When you stop a running instance, the following happens:

The instance performs a normal shutdown and stops running; its status changes to stopping and then stopped.

Any Amazon EBS volumes remain attached to the instance, and their data persists.

Any data stored in the RAM of the host computer or the instance store volumes of the host computer is gone.

EC2-Classic: We release the public and private IP addresses for the instance when you stop the instance, and assign new ones when you restart it.

EC2-VPC: The instance retains its private IP addresses when stopped and restarted. We release the public IP address and assign a new one when you restart it.

You instance must have got New Public IP . Please check and try to login to your server with new IP .